# Python show personalised error

Tags: python, search, web-scraping

I have created this scraper to search for online streams save me going through all the popups.

How could I make it return ''no streams available'' if search comes up empty

```
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
from urlparse import urljoin

user_input   = raw_input ("Search for Team = "); 


resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://idimsports.eu/football.html") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))

base_url = "http://idimsports.eu" 
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(''+user_input)): 
    print urljoin(base_url, link['href'])
```

Comment: How would you determine if the search comes up empty?  And what do you want to return this message to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
...
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(''+user_input))
if links:
    for link in links:
        print urljoin(base_url, link['href'])
else:
    print  "no streams available"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save your `find_all` method call to a variable and check the length of it:

```
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
from urlparse import urljoin

user_input   = raw_input ("Search for Team = "); 


resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://idimsports.eu/football.html") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))

base_url = "http://idimsports.eu"
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(''+user_input))
if len(links) == 0:
    print "no streams available"
else:
    for link in links: 
        print urljoin(base_url, link['href'])
```

Comment: Just curious why you accepted and then unaccepted my answer?